# Problem displaying a linq query in a datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Hello: I am working on a C# project that reads an XML file and returns a list of lists. When I want to display a list I do this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFooQuery = from t in myLists.SelectMany( l => l.bar)
                              orderby t.StartTime descending
                              select t;
dataGridView1.DataSource = myFooQuery.ToList();
```

My problem is that when I do it that way, you can't click on the column header to sort the datagridview. I tried myFooQuery.AsQueryable(), but then nothing shows up in the datagridview even though the query count is what I expect. Am I just missing something obvious, or do I have to use .Tolist()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> myFooQuery = from t in myLists.SelectMany( l => l.bar)
                              orderby t.StartTime descending
                              select t;

DataView myDataView = myFooQuery.AsDataView();

dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataView;
```

EDIT - commented out line

//dataGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: I just tried to do this, and I am using Visual C# 2010, and I do not have a dataGridView1.DataBind().

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to include that.  Have you tried it with out?